# Disabling highcharts stacked bar's highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I'm trying to use Highcharts stacked bar graph. I have two series to create the effect of fading like the picture below.

[image: stacked bar]

But when I use stacked bar, it highlights both of the series, like this.
[image: bar chart using highcharts]

What I'm trying to do is disabling highlight, so I can get the fading effect I want. So far I tried disabling with `hover enable:false` and `inactive:true` but nothing worked... By the way when I only use one series, I can disable it with both options.
Here is my files.

```js
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'graph',
        type: 'bar',
        styledMode: true,
    },
    
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    
    xAxis: { //actually y axis adds more variable in y axis
        categories: ['Lisansüstü', 'Lisans', 'Önlisans']
    },
    
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },
    },
    
    tooltip:{
        enabled: false
    },
    
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    
    plotOptions:{
        series:{
            stacking: 'normal',
            states: {
                hover: {
                  enabled: false,
                }
              }
        }
    },
   
    series: [{
        name: '',
        data: [5, 3, 4]
      }, {
        name: '',
        data: [2, 2, 3]
      },
]

};


var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

```css
  .highcharts-color-0 {
    fill: rgba(10, 89, 114, 0.5);
  }
   .highcharts-color-1 {
    fill: rgba(10, 89, 114, 0.2);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    plotOptions:{
    series:{
        stacking: 'normal',
        enableMouseTracking: false,
    }
},
```

After I searched so long, 3 minutes after posting this question solved the problem... This works fine!!